# Public Service Announcement: IE9 rendering oddity when FORMs tags improperly laid out

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, frameset

Greetings and salutations!

I've put together a nice floating form CSS file for some pretty forms with minimal HTML code that work swimmingly under FF and Chrome (note the absence of IE in that list [done Done DONNNNE!]).

So in testing under IE I was getting a weird break in the FIELDSET (which was styled with a border). Under IE9 it looked as though there were 2 FIELDSETs when in fact this is only one...

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XbrWx/11/)

## Chrome (under Win7):

[image: Chrome]

## Firefox (under Win7):

[image: Firefox]

## IE9 (under Win7):

[image: Internet Exploder]

## UPDATE (including answer from below)

In the end, the cause of this was an end FORM being lost in the middle of the FIELDSET (as JSFiddle even complained about).

Comment: Please note that SO is a _question_ and _answer_ site -- not really a blogging platform. If you feel strongly about this content remaining on SO, [please pretend you're asking a question, and then give the answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough! I did go looking for a "post" rather than "ask a question" link... Will note to pretend next time =) At least I used a PSA prefix!

Comment: Oh, I'm not suggesting waiting for next time -- I'm suggesting that you [edit] this to ask a question and then give an answer. :)

Comment: Well... as I'm sub 100 I canna answer my own Q's without waiting 8 hours. So I'd be happy to give you the cred it you'd like to submit an answer =)

Comment: 104 now! :) Go for it. (I surely don't need more. hehe.)

Comment: Thanks! Answering myself feels so... dirty =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the misplaced end FORM tag (even JSFiddle spotted it)!